# SplitViewController opens new details view instead of updating the existing one (iPhone 6+)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa, iphone-6-plus

I am making an app with a SplitViewController.

When I use my app on iPhone 6 Plus on landscape mode (that splits the view, like in the settings app), I got that (which is normal):

[image: screen2]

But when I click a cell to update the detail view with the corresponding image, I got something weird: 
[image: screen3]
Another detail view is popping from the left side of the screen. It should be updating the existing detail view with the new image instead.

Do you know why is that happening and how to get a correct behavior? Maybe I've done something wrong in the storyboard?

[EDIT] : 
Here is my prepareForSegue :

```
MY_Img *img = [self.imgs
objectAtIndex:self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.row];
/*
DetailViewController *detailController = (DetailViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
[detailController setDetailItem:img];
*/

((AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).detailItem=img;
```

I had to use that because the commented part makes the program crash. I don't know why. Do you know that's wrong ?

They, I get back the `img` in the DetailController with that :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

[self setDetailItem: ((AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).detailItem];

}
```

Comment: Here is my storyboard : [screen1](http://imgur.com/voVuZUa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The segue from the cell of the Master table view should go to the navigation controller that contains the Detail viewcontroller.

You may find other errors if you compare your code with a newly created project from the Master-Detail template.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. I added the code where I set the infos in the detail view controller in the master view controller.